# Promise is not resolving in useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am getting response from api which i need to render.

following is the sample response (relevant fields only):

```
 [
    {
        ...other fields,
        "latitude": "33.5682166",
        "longitude": "73.207334",
       
       
    },
    {
       ...otherfields,
        "latitude": "33.5602917176197",
        "longitude": "73.22683267327477",
      
    }
]
```

i need to render the following component using above response (relevant code only):

```
import { getReverseGeocodedLocation } from "../../../services/getLocation";
import { useEffect, useState,memo } from "react";



 type Props = {
  category_id: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  price: string;
  lat: string;
  lng: string;
  category: string;
  source: ImageSourcePropType;
};

const RecentPost: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {

...otherCode,
 
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      //This promise below is not resolving for first few entries of api res
      //For later entries in the array from api res, it resolves.
      // if only single entry is sent from api then it resolves successfully
      

      const address = await getReverseGeocodedLocation(
        parseFloat(props.lat),
        parseFloat(props.lng)
      );

      address.description && setDescription(address.description);
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
        ...allTheComponentsBasedOnApiResponse,
  );
};

export default memo(RecentPost, () => true);
```

Following is the parent component which renders above component:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import RecentPost from "./RecentPost";

const RecentPosts: React.FC = () => {
  const [recent_posts, set_recent_posts] = useState<rent_post_brief[]>([]);
  const [posts_loading, set_posts_loading] = useState(true);
  const city_name = useAppSelector((state) => state.location.city_name);

...otherStuff,

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        set_posts_loading(true);

        const res = await rentApi.get<rent_post_brief[]>(`/rent/recent-posts`, {
          params: {
            city: city_name === "All cities" ? undefined : city_name,
            filter,
          },
        });

        set_recent_posts(res.data);
      } finally {
        set_posts_loading(false);
      }
    })();
  }, [city_name, filter]);

  return (
    <>
      ...otherStuff,
        {posts_loading ? (
          <LoadingText />
        ) : recent_posts.length > 0 ? (
          recent_posts.map((item) => {
            return (
              <RecentPost
                id={item.id}
                category_id={item.category.id}
                key={`${item.id}`}
                source={{ uri: item.uploaded_media[0].file }}
                title={item.title}
                price={item.price}
                lat={item.latitude}
                lng={item.longitude}
                category={item.category.title}
              />
            );
          })
        ) : (
          <NoPosts />
        )}
      </View>
     ...otherStuff,
    </>
  );
};

export const NoPosts: React.FC = () => (
  <Animated.Text style={styles.no_posts} entering={FadeIn} exiting={FadeOut}>
    No posts for current settings, kindly either change city or change filter.
  </Animated.Text>
);

export default RecentPosts;
```

Following is the function which returns the promise:

```
import * as Location from "expo-location";

/**
 * Takes location coordiantes and returns string location
 * @param latitude
 * @param longitude
 * @returns Promise resolving to string location
 */
export const getReverseGeocodedLocation = async (
  latitude: number,
  longitude: number
) => {
  const reverse_geocoded_results = await Location.reverseGeocodeAsync({
    latitude,
    longitude,
  });

  const result = reverse_geocoded_results[0];

  const { city, district } = result;

  return { city, description: district };
};
```

Comment: @pilchard This component is only loaded when lat and lng are available and i only need to render it once, i had tried that already but still promise doesn't resolve for first element

Comment: then you'll need to post specific debugging details, or a minimal example showing the problem. Possibly no valid reverselookup?

Comment: I tried to follow the flow using console logs, problem is that promise just doesn't resolve for first element. like if console.log is added after the await in the function that i have written it just doesn't show. same happens for few other entries.  While for other entries it resolves.

Comment: @pilchard can it be the case that before it can resolve, This function is called by the next element in the array thus stopping the previous Promise. i mean i am little noob with promises. but as per my understanding each component is calling this function separately and promise should resolve independantly. right ?

Comment: yes, each call is independent. Have you tried debugging `getReverseGeocodedLocation`? or calling it specifically with the `lat` and `lng` of one of the components that isn't rendering?

Comment: yup. i tried by using only single element from the api res. it contained those lat lng which arent rerendering. once it was sent as single element then it rendered successfully. There isin't one value actually. i even changed the values. what ever the values in the first element of the response. First element promise doesn't resolve. it only resolves if only one element is sent from api.

Comment: @pilchard Thanks for your help. i think i got the issue. Following is written in the docs of getReverseGeocodedLocation:

Geocoding is resource consuming and has to be used reasonably. Creating too many requests at a time can result in an error, so they have to be managed properly. It's also discouraged to use geocoding while the app is in the background and its results won't be shown to the user immediately.

Comment: Oh great, glad you possibly isolated the problem

Comment: it's not working as of now, however i suppose i would need to use some other service like google geocode api for this purpose. Anyhow Thank you. Take care.

Answer (score -1):

Finally managed to isolate the problem.

It is due to the async function of expo-location i.e reverseGeocodeAsync that i am using. It is written in the docs (https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/location/#locationreversegeocodeasynclocation-options):

"Note: Geocoding is resource consuming and has to be used reasonably. Creating too many requests at a time can result in an error, so they have to be managed properly. It's also discouraged to use geocoding while the app is in the background and its results won't be shown to the user immediately."

I was sending multiple requests using this function which was creating the problem. Decided to change my approach after reading this.